# How to share web application on linux?

Tags: linux, networking

I host a web application on my laptop and I access it using 'localhost:9080/abc.com' and lets assume my IP is '192.168.10.20'

Now, I want my colleague to access this web application from his system 'web browser' by typing in '192.168.10.20:9080/abc.com'

As laptop is owned by 'company' I cannot install (or) use any third party softwares

How can I manage this on RHEL 6?

Comment: Is `http://192.168.10.20:9080/abc.com`  not working?

Comment: Yes because we have not setup anything and not sure where and how to start 'sharing' on linux for this activity.  I see lots of blogs for sharing folders, files etc but could not find a blog for this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on the same network (LAN) then a client who connects to 192.168.10.20:9080 should have no problems (assuming the web aplication also listens to requests other than localhost).

If abc.com is just an "alias" you set up in your hosts file then no other person than yourself will be able to use abc.com to connect  to 192.168.1.10.20, unless they have the same alias in their hosts file.

If you purchased a domain abc.com and set up it up to redirect to 192.168.10.20 it should work. But usually there are delays associated with updating a DNS so the time it takes for abc.com to be updated can take even a day.

Now if you have your colleagues on a different network (for example they want to connect from their homes when the laptop is connected to the internet at your place) it won't work with a bit of fiddling. Basically, when they try to connect the router gets a request from the client to connect to port 9080, but the router doesn't know what to do with it so nothing happens. You have to set up port forwarding in your routers settings so that all incoming traffic on port 9080 gets sent to 192.168.10.20.

And when they try to connect that way, they can not use the 192.168.10.20 ip adress, because it always refers to a adress on the local network. They have to use your external ip adress (google what is my ip adress).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  We both are on same LAN.  But, the web server currently runs only on 'localhost'.  How can I share this now? or how can I make the application to listen on port 9080 on client?  And I use Websphere to host the files

Comment: Well it should work. Did you try `ping`ing 192.168.10.20? If the request doesn't fail then it's likely an issue with the webapp or the firewall (likely iptables, but I'm not sure what RHEL uses by default). Verify that the configuration of the firewall on your laptop allows connections on port 9080.

Comment: We both are able to ping each other.  We will check firewall settings